# Oracle select query using DISTINCT on groups of fields with multiple joins

Tags: sql, oracle, join

So the query at the moment is:

```
SELECT 
    i.id, i.name, i.status, i.date_return, 
    a.category, a.year, a.type,
    c.forename, c.lastname, c.type, c.dob, c.address
FROM item i
RIGHT JOIN account a ON a.item_id = i.id
LEFT JOIN client c ON c.account_id = a.id
ORDER BY i.date_return
```

The problem is I need to return a result set where the following column groups
are unique (i.id), (a.category, a.year) and (c.forename, c.lastname, c.type, c.dob) for every row.

Is there a way to do this using DISTINCT on joins in Oracle?

Comment: Does `select distinct` do what you want?  If not, edit your question and show sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by unique "column groups"? If you want to collapse **account** rows with the same **item_id**, **category** and **year** but different **type**, you cannot include **account.type** in the select. 
Same for **client.address**, while (supposing **item.id** is a unique key) all fields from **item** can be used.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
i.id, i.name, i.status, i.date_return, 
a.category, a.year,
c.forename, c.lastname, c.type, c.dob
FROM item i
RIGHT JOIN account a ON a.item_id = i.id
LEFT JOIN client c ON c.account_id = a.id
ORDER BY i.date_return
```